# Does the standard 4/3 integrality gap for TSP example work for Euclidean TSP?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, traveling-salesman

The standard LP gap example for the held karp relaxation  for TSP

min $ c^tx  $

$x(\delta(S)) \geq 2   $

$x(\delta(v))=2 $

$x \geq 0$

Is to have two triangles and three long paths connecting the corresponding vertices yielding a 4/3 integrality gap example.

Does this not work for Euclidean TSP?  I saw this paper here  [2014] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167637714001205

Indicating the previous known gap was 8/7 instead.